# Manage WIndows clients in the Azure cloud

Tags: windows, azure, domain, cloud, user-management

I'm looking for a solution for the following scenario:

We are planing to install several Windows 10 systems (about 30 to 50 PCs).

We want to create user centrally, and also want to push group policies to the machines.

So I think we need a Microsoft AD Server. But we don't want to have the server locally at our side so we need to go to the Microsoft cloud.

We already searched at https://azure.microsoft.com but we are unsure which product(s) are the correct for our use case.

Can anyone enlighten us ?

We think we need the Azure Active Directory (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory/)

But we are unsure if this is all we need to manage our user accounts and our machines in the cloud.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to look at [Microsoft intune](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/what-is-intune)

Microsoft Intune is a cloud-based service in the enterprise mobility management (EMM) space that helps enable your workforce to be productive while keeping your corporate data protected. Similar to other Azure services, Microsoft Intune is available in the Azure portal. With Intune, you can:

- Manage the mobile devices and PCs your workforce uses to access company data.
- Manage the mobile devices and PCs your workforce uses to access
  company data.
- Manage the mobile apps your workforce uses.
- Protect your company information by helping to control the way your
  workforce accesses and shares it.
- Ensure devices and apps are compliant with company security
  requirements.

Comment: This is indeed what we looked for. Thanks for your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

IF you Azure AD you cant push GPOs however you can create a server and promote it to DC
Azure Microsoft Managed Desktop which can use in case you are referring to the VDI else Intune is the way to go 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/managed-desktop/

Comment: Can you explain the part  

> you can create a server and promote it to DC Azure Microsoft Managed Desktop

For me after reading your link I'm getting to the point where I think "Microsoft Managed Desktop" is not really the thing what we wan't. We don't need devices which are completely managed by Microsoft. We are really only looking for a way to get the possibility to have an Domain server (for managing users and GPOs for the PCs) In the later run maybe it would be usefull to postphone windows updates but this is not needed at first.